# Having tight border around a text box

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to display matrix D in a matlab figure.  This is the code:

```
figure;
text('HorizontalAlignment'  , 'center'  ,...
'string'               , num2str(D)   ,...
'FontSize'             , 20       ,...
'BackgroundColor'      , 'w');  axis off
```

How can I get rid of the gray border?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way based on the answer found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31841-fit-figure-size-to-textbox).

The trick is to use an textbox annotation object and set its position such that it fills the figure in which it's created using normalized units.

Here is the code, which I modified a bit:

```
clear
clc
close all

D = magic(5);

hText = annotation('textbox','Position',[.2 .8 .2 .2], 'FitBoxToText','on','String',num2str(D),'HorizontalAlignment'  , 'center'  ,...
'string'               , num2str(D)   ,...
'FontSize'             , 20       ,...
'BackgroundColor'      , 'w'); 

set(hText,'Units','pixels'); 

Text_Pos = get(hText,'Position');

fPos = get(gcf,'Position'); 
fPos(3:4)=Text_Pos(3:4) 

set(gcf,'Position',fPos)
set(hText,'Units','norm','Position',[0 0 1 1])
```

And a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: So @Seeda did you try my suggestion??

Comment: Yes, I did.  Thank you.  But the textbox was not fully displayed.  So resizing was required which is frustrating.  I guess textbox is not appropriate for what I was trying to do  The cleaner solution would be to create latex table code since I was going to embed the textbox in a Latex document. @Benoit_11

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get rid of the gray border?

Set the figure's background to match the color of your textbox.

```
figure('color','w');
```